Java use the sdk path does not exist anymore even after restart computer, vscode, terminal
So I installed wrong version java at first (jdk-19) then I unintall that and installed the latest (jdk-23). After I install, I do
In System Envariables,
set JAVA_HOME

set Path

Then I restart my laptop
Open VScode, run
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4391], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.24.4 on channel stable at C:\SDK\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 603104015d (7 days ago), 2024-10-24 08:01:25 -0700
    • Engine revision db49896cf2
    • Dart version 3.5.4
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\thong\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:SDKJavajdk-19\bin\java
    X Cannot execute C:SDKJavajdk-19\bin\java to determine the version

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.11.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.11.35327.3
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)

[√] VS Code (version 1.95.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\thong\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.98.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • V2342 (mobile)    • 10AE3E1GYQ000KX • android-arm64  • Android 14 (API 34)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows         • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.4391]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome          • web-javascript • Google Chrome 130.0.6723.70
    • Edge (web)        • edge            • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 130.0.2849.56

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

 flutter analyze --suggestions    

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ General Info                                                      │
│ [√] App Name: getx_flutter                                        │
│ [√] Supported Platforms: android, ios                             │
│ [√] Is Flutter Package: yes                                       │
│ [√] Uses Material Design: yes                                     │
│ [√] Is Plugin: no                                                 │
│ [X] Java/Gradle/Android Gradle Plugin:                            │
│ Incompatible Java/Gradle versions.                                │
│ Java Version: null, Gradle Version: 8.3                           │
│                                                                   │
│ See the link below for more information:                          │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java │
│                                                                   │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

flutter doctor --android-licenses

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:SDKJavajdk-19

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (C:\Users\thong\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat): "exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/to/windows-android-setup for detailed instructions.

C:\SDK\Java\jdk-19 is my old path but I deleted that before I installed jdk-23 and I chose the default path.
But why it show C:SDKJavajdk-19 not C:\SDK\Java\jdk-19

You need to get rid of that old one ending in javapath
